# How do i get my CRUD functions to work in GORM?

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

For an exercise I need to learn to use GORM. To be specific, I need to use CRUD functions in one package to get the tasks in main.go functional. I dont need the entire exercise done for me per se, getting one function to work and a clear explanation is more than enough to be a reference for me probably. Here is the code in the three packages I have along with some random appropriate data:

student.go

```
package model

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Student struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string
    Age    int
    City   string
    Adress string
}

func PrintStudents(students []Student) {
    for _, s := range students {
        println(s.Name, s.Age, s.City, s.Adress)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    task "gorm-basis"
    "gorm-basis/main/model"
)

func main() {
    task.InitDatabase(&model.Student{})

    // Create
    task.CreateStudent("Jan", 18, "Ede", "Dorpsweg 1")
    task.CreateStudent("Piet", 19, "Veenendaal", "Dorpsweg 2")
    task.CreateStudent("Klaas", 20, "Ede", "Dorpsweg 3")
    task.CreateStudent("Klaasje", 20, "Ede", "Dorpsweg 369552")

    // Read
    fmt.Println("Student Jan:")
    model.PrintStudents([]model.Student{task.GetStudentByName("Jan")})
    fmt.Println("All students:")
    model.PrintStudents(task.GetAllStudents())
    fmt.Println("All students from city Ede:")
    model.PrintStudents(task.GetStudentsByWoonplaats("Ede"))

    // Update - update the age of Jan to 19
    jan := task.GetStudentByName("Jan")
    jan.Age = 19
    task.UpdateStudent(jan)

    // Update - update the city of residence and the adress of the student with the name Piet
    piet := task.GetStudentByName("Piet")
    piet.City = "Amersfoort"
    piet.Adress = "Arnhemsestraat 16"
    task.UpdateStudent(piet)

    // Delete - delete product
    wrongEntry := task.GetStudentByName("Klaasje")
    task.DeleteStudent(wrongEntry)

}
```

task.go

```
package task

import (
    "github.com/glebarez/sqlite"
    "gorm-basis/main/model"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

/*
*
De variabele db bestaat alleen in deze package. Deze variabele is een pointer naar een gorm.DB object.
Deze variabele is niet zichtbaar buiten deze package, zodat er maar één database connectie is.
Wil je deze toch van buiten de package kunnen benaderen, dan kan je de GetDBConnection() functie gebruiken.
*/
var db *gorm.DB

func connectToDb() *gorm.DB {
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("studenten.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db
}

func GetDBConnection() *gorm.DB {
    return db
}

func createDatabase(model interface{}) {
    db.AutoMigrate(model)
}

func InitDatabase(model interface{}) {
    connectToDb()
    createDatabase(model)
    DeleteAllStudents()
}

/**
Implement the CRUD-functies for the Student struct under here.
*/

func CreateStudent(name string, age int, city string, adress string) error {

    return nil
}

func GetAllStudents() []model.Student {
    return nil
}

// This function there is only one student with one specific name.
func GetStudentByName(name string) model.Student {
    return model.Student{}
}

func GetStudentsByWoonplaats(city string) []model.Student {
    return nil
}

func UpdateStudent(student model.Student) {

}

func DeleteStudent(student model.Student) {

}

func DeleteAllStudents() {
    allStudents := GetAllStudents()
    for _, student := range allStudents {
        db.Unscoped().Delete(&student)
    }
}
```

I have tried to translate most of the terms since some were in Dutch. Student.go and main.go are supposed to remain untouched and the exercise done in task.go.

I have tried several ways to get this to work, every time I expected a functional database, but I ended up with a lot of error messages every time.

Comment: What is the first error you see? I have some concerns about project structure and packages but not necessarily the problem. For starters the CreateStudent function does nothing. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take `CreateStudent` for instance:

```golang
func CreateStudent(name string, age int, city string, adress string) error {
    result := db.Create(&Student{Name: name, Age: age, City: city, Adress: adress})

    return result.Error
}
```

Here you just need to simply call `Create`, pass the needed `Student` instance and return an error from the result.

The same way is about updating students (call `Update`) and deleting students (call `Delete`).

To get students you just need to use `Where` (optional) and `Find`

P.S. if you get errors try to find out what's going on. If you can't just ask the **new** question here